# Error occured while executing stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using two servers.
one is testing server and another is main server.
When I execute a stored procedure on testing server it executes fine.
But when I am executing the same stored procedure on main server I am getting below error:

Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. Created with MySQL 50077, now running 50158. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.

I am not able to understand this error.

my stored procedure is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE db_test.test(IN thedate1 varchar(100),IN thedate2 varchar(100),OUT greatdate varchar(100))
BEGIN
IF(thedate1 > thedate2)
THEN
SET greatdate = thedate1;
ELSE
SET greatdate = thedate2;
END IF;
END;
```

Please help.......

Comment: Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.

Comment: think its server setting issue

Comment: You might have written this procedure to learn it, but note, that there's also the `GREATEST()` function, which does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`mysql_upgrade -u[user] -p [password]`

Don't forget to restart afterwards.

This should fix things